# Apache: Redirect all .html AND .php requests to folder + WordPress

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, wordpress, apache2

After a relaunch I have a bunch of dead backlinks pointing at URLs with `.php` or `.html` file-extensions. It would be nice to redirect them in bulk using `.htaccess` and the mod_rewrite module.

The redirection of `.html` requests are working fine, however, I can’t get the redirect of `.php` URLs to work. Please note that I use WordPress so there has to be an exemption of the `/wp-admin/` folder.

This is what I've come up with so far, but it doesn't work for `.php`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect http requests to https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L]

# Redirect html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L] 

# Redirect php NOT WORKING
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L] 

# Lines below come from WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Can you spot where I'm wrong? Or am I completely lost?

Comment: Did you intend to _not_ do 301 redirects? Because that is how you have currently set it up.

Comment: Yes, it's intended because I want to avoid a caching of the redirect until I'm sure everything works correct.

Comment: Well, you aren't doing 302 redirects either. So that's a little confusing.

Comment: @michael-hampton You’re absolutely correct about this. That is the necessity I lacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> # Redirect html
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html
> RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L]
> ```

This isn't a "redirect", as in an "external 3xx redirect", that you appear to be suggesting. If you are seeing a "redirect" then either something else is doing that, or you are seeing a cached response. The directive above is an *internal rewrite* - the URL in the browser's address bar does not change (this would be *bad* for SEO).

The `RewriteCond` directive is also superfluous in this instance... it just means you are checking for `.html` on the requested URL *twice*.

If you want to remove the `.html` extension via a redirect then you just need something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R,L]
```

However, to remove the `.php` extension from the URL then you also need to avoid redirecting `index.php` (that the WordPress front-controller *rewrites* to), or only make sure you are checking the initial request, not the rewritten request. For example:

```
# Redirect php (avoiding "/wp-admin/" and "/index.php")
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
```

To make sure you are only testing the initial request and not a rewritten request, then you can use a *condition* like:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
```

This simply checks that the `REDIRECT_STATUS` *environment variable* is empty - which it is on the initial request. After the first successful *rewrite* it gets set to "200" (as in 200 OK HTTP status).

Change the `R` to `R=301` if this is intended to be a permanent redirect, but only once you have confirmed that it's working OK.

You should also avoid adding your own custom directives to the `# BEGIN WordPress` block as these could be overridden by WordPress itself. Instead these directives should be written *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` block, together with your HTTP to HTTPS redirect (which isn't actually a *redirect* either - you *need* the `R` flag on the `RewriteRule`).

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought that `RewriteRule` is sufficient for a redirect and omitted `[R]` because I wanted to avoid a caching of the redirect.
Thank you for the edit and the additional explanation, too – it really helped me a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. There is an exception... if you specify an absolute URL (ie. scheme + hostname) in the `RewriteRule` _substitution_ then an external redirect (302 - temporary) is triggered even when the `R` flag is omitted. So, your HTTP to HTTPS directive will still have resulted in a redirect (302, not 301), but the  directives that handle the `.html` and `.php` extensions would have resulted in _internal rewrites_ (as mentioned above). Generally, 302 (temporary) redirects are not cached by the browser. `[R]` and `[R=302]` both represent 302 temporary redirects, as 302 is the default.